# AngularJs, change color to a single item in a (repeat)list

Tags: angularjs, list

I'm new to angularjs. This is my issue:

This is my data:

```
$scope.products = [
                       {item: "Milk", alreadyTook: false},
                       {item: "Bread", alreadyTook: false},
                       {item: "Cheese", alreadyTook: true}
                      ];
```

This is my controller:

```
var mymodal = angular.module('app', []);
mymodal.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.toggleSelection = function(itemObject) { 
        itemObject.item=itemObject.item;
        itemObject.alreadyTook=!itemObject.alreadyTook;
    };
});
```

This is my html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-cloak ng-controller="myCtrl">

<ul class="w3-ul">
    <li ng-repeat="x in products" ng-click="toggleSelection(x)" ng-style="{ 'color' : ({{x.alreadyTook}}) ? 'red' : 'black' }">{{x.item}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to set/unset the foreground color of the single li text selected(by mouse click); I don't want to use pure js or jquery.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only mistaking the `ng-style`, you don't need interpolation, just use `x.alreadyTook` without `{{ }}`:

```
ng-style="{ 'color' : (x.alreadyTook) ? 'red' : 'black' }"
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/6nrpu3f1/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You can apply classes conditionally:

```
ng-class="{taken: x.alreadyTaken}"
```

css:

```
#mylist li {color: black}
#mylist li.taken{color: red}
```

From the top of my head I can't imagine a use-case for `ng-style` that I wouldn't consider bad practice.

Using ng-class with the appropriate classes is way easier to maintain than setting styles from within the template.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the {{}}'s like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in products" ng-click="toggleSelection(x)" ng-style="{ 'color' : (x.alreadyTook) ? 'red' : 'black' }">{{x.item}}
      </li>
```